# Installing F5 load balancer on Linux

Tags: linux, load-balancing, f5

I need to do load balancing using f5 only.How to install f5 on linux plateform. From where I can get the setup file and any tutorial of configuring it.I downloaded the bigip-11.3.0.39.0 file from F5 site but its in vmdk format.

Comment: Not possible AFAIK. Need to launch it as a virtual machine.

Comment: thanks Robby.Is there no way at all of installing F5 on Linux?

Comment: The F5 already runs on a heavily modified version of red hat. The F5 software runs inside of Linux in a micro-kernel and TMM actually stands for Traffic Management Micro-kernel

Answer (score 2):

you can intstall the VE edition on VMware ESXi and NO you cannot install on linux

Comment: thanks,i scrapped the approach and used simple Apache loadbalancer.

Answer (score 0):

The f5 big-ip balancer itself is already including an OS (most likely CentOS). You can launch an virtual instance using its image.